# react-hook-form HTML select not submitting selected value

Tags: react-hook-form

**Description**

I have a simple form that only has one HTML select and a submit button.

The select control only has 3 options:

- "Initial value" which has a value of -1
- "A" which has a value of 5
- "B" which has a value of 10

I need to have access to the onchange event to perform some aditional processing when the value
changes and before the form is submitted. To keep things short, in this example it will be just a console.log invocation.

However, no matter which option I pick, when I click the "Send" button, it always sends the -1 value.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Pick any value, at the console you can see the selected value (5, 10, etc)
2. Press the submit button. Check the console.

**Code**

```
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

export default function HTMLSelectTest() {
const {register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
const regSel= register("sel");
const options = [
    {name: "Initial value", code: -1},
    {name: "A", code: 5},
    {name: "B", code:10}
]
    
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("data to be sent");
    console.log(data);    
};    

return (
    <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(onSubmit) }>
        <select ref={regSel.ref}
        onChange={(e) => {
            regSel.onChange(e);            
            console.log(e.target.value); // let's say this is the additional processing 
        }}
        onBlur={(e) => {
            regSel.onBlur(e);
        }} 
        >
            {
                options.map((o, index) => {
                    return (
                        <option value={o.code} key={o.code}>
                            {o.name}
                        </option>
                    );
                })             
            }
        </select>

        <button>
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, you are just missing the `name` field to allow RHF to bind the updated value to corresponding field.

```js
<select
  ref={selRef.ref}
  name={selRef.name} // add name
  onChange={(e) => {
    selRef.onChange(e);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }}
>
...
</select>
```

Here is the codesandbox for demo:

[image: Edit RHF]

---

If you want to preserve `onBlur` as well and don't want to add `onBlur={selRef.onBlur}` manually, you can use destructure and spread operator to do so.

```js
const { onChange: selOnChange, ...selRef } = register("sel");
```

Here is the codesandbox for demo:

[image: Edit RHF]